# NSTableView edits not changing NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nstableview

I have a Class that stores some strings along with a BOOL flag that is set to YES if one of the strings has been updated.

I have a NSTableView that displays the strings in my class. The view is controlled via separate controller class and the view is fed by an NSMutableArray.

The GUI stuff seems to work fine in terms of displaying data and allowing me to edit the cells in the table view. The problem I am having is the edits don't change the objects stored in the NSMutableArray. I have some debug code to print out the strings when I close the app, and none of the changes made in the GUI show up in the objects at this point. Setting a break point where those values are changed shows me the objects are indeed changed, but those changes seem to get lost. How can I get any changes I make in the view to persist in the object stored in the NSMutableArray backing the NSTableView?

Here is how I am coding:

```
// my class .h file

@interface Snip : NSObject <NSMutableCopying>

@property (assign) int64_t  id_num;
@property (assign) BOOL     changed;
@property NSMutableString   *name;
@property NSMutableString   *text;
@property (copy) NSString   *language;


// my class .m file

import "Snip.h"

@implementation Snip

@synthesize id_num;
@synthesize name;
@synthesize text;
@synthesize changed;
@synthesize language;
```

method from my controller class

```
// edit table values
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
  Snip *sn = [snippet_list objectAtIndex:row];

  [sn setChanged:YES];

  [sn setValue:object forKey:[tableColumn identifier]];

  NSLog(@"Change: %@",sn.name);
}
```

That last NSLog statement displays the change I made in the GUI. Also, the setChanged:YES is lost as well when I print the NSMutableArray contents when closing the app.

Comment: Do you have any initialisation code that happens to be run after your changes are made? Any chance you could put a breakpoint in there?

Comment: @Monolo -> I believe you have sent me down the right path. I am investigating and will report back.

Comment: @Monolo -> Turns out your question was just what I needed to hear. I was running the initialization twice, and thus resetting the array back to what the database had. Appreciate the help. I'll give you the accepted answer check mark if you make up an answer that addresses this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is often due to the data being initialised again at some point after being changed by the user.

You can catch this problem by setting a breakpoint (or `NSLog` statement) in your initialisation code.